# Center positioning for my popup dialog box

Tags: popup, positioning, center

I have used a dialog box in my application which is causing trouble with it's alignment as my page has grown in content.

Till my page was short and had less content , it used to popup up nicely at the center of my page . But , now my page has grown vertically , and once I click on my popup , I want it to be positioned at the center of my screen instead of scrolling everytime to the center of the page.

**#bdy_content** is the parent/root div in my page.

**target** element is actually a **span** as given below :

```
<span adname="testtraffickerbannertext" adtag="Click here!" title="showAdTag">
   <a class="banner" href="javascript:void(0);" title="showAdTag">Ad Tag</a>
</span>
```

Hereis my **centerPopup()** function :

```
function centerPopup(e){
var target = e.target.title;
//request data for centering
var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var windowHeight = $('#bdy_content').height();
    if(windowHeight < 600){
        windowHeight = 600;
    }
var popupHeight = $("#" + target).height();
var popupWidth = $("#" + target).width();
//centering
$("#"+ target).css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,

    //Instead, we go with where the click was
   //   "top" : e.pageY - 20,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
});
//only need force for IE6

$("#previewCurtain").css({
    "height": windowHeight
});
window.scrollTo(0,windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2);
```

}

Also , I can't change my existing popup plugin as I have reused it this throughout my site and it will be a big overhead .

Comment: R u sure you can given whole of the code??? Please use jsfiddle and update the code and show the real problem